# using LINQ how can i concatenate string properties from itesm in a collection

Tags: c#, linq

i have a list of objects in a collection.  Each object has a string property called Issue.  I want to concatenate the issue from all of the items in the collection and put them into a single string. what is the cleanest way of doing this using LINQ.

here is manual way:

```
 string issueList = "";
 foreach (var item in collection)
 {
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Issue)
       {
             issueList = issueList + item.Issue + ", ";
       }
 }
 //Remove the last comma
 issueList = issueList.Remove(issueList.Length - 2);
 return issueList;
```

Comment: I don't see anything messy about that.

Comment: @Nick - i just thought it would be cleaner in a single LINQ statement

Comment: @Nick: You don't? Why not? It's a large amount of annoying repetitive code.

Comment: @Slaks, I wasn't aware of doing it the way you have in your answer. It looks much better.

Comment: @Nick: It may not be "messy", but it's slow (it has to copy the accumulated string once per input string) and buggy (it throws an exception if the output string is empty).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can write

```
return String.Join(", ", collection.Select(o => o.Issue));
```

In .Net 3.5, you'll need to add `.ToArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ToDelimitedString from [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview).