# "The element access is not permitted" error when trying to concatenate object names with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, runtime-error

I am doing my first steps in LINQ. Using LINQ to SQL, I am trying to write a relatively simple query, which, given a mouse with adenocarcinoma in the lungs and mammary glands, will return the tumors of the mouse, prepared for showing in a gridview formatted like

> | Adenocarcinoma | Lungs, Mammary glands, |

Similar to the example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5615665/1983448), I wrote the query

```
var tumors = from tumor in dc.Tumors
             where tumor.FK_Mouse == mouse.ID
             select new
             {
                 Name=tumor.Name, 
                 Organs=string.Join(", ", tumor.Organs.Select(t => t.Name))
             };
```

What I get is an error. The original text (my IIS is localized to German) is:

> Der Elementzugriff "System.String Name" von "ToyApp.Organ" ist für den
>   Typ "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ToyApp.Organ]" nicht
>   zulässig.

I couldn't find a translation back to the original error. My best try to translating it is:

> The element access "System.String Name" of "ToyApp.Organ" is not permitted for the type 
>   "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ToyApp.Organ]"

If I select Organs=tumor.Organs instead of trying to join the organ names, everything is working fine and I am getting a collection of organs for each tumor, so the problem must be in the concatenation and not in the ORM.

Googling the German error message finds no results at all, and neither does my backtranslation (which may be too far from the original wording to be any good).

Any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the concatenation is simply not supported within the LINQ to SQL part. So fetch all the data you need to in the SQL part, then switch to in-process LINQ to Objects for the concatenation:

```
var tumors = dc.Tumors
               .Where(tumor => tumor.FK_Mouse == mouse.ID)
               .Select(tumor => new { 
                   tumor.Name, 
                   Organs = tumor.Organs.Select(o => o.Name)
               })
               .AsEnumerable() // Switch to LINQ to Objects
               .Select(tumor => new {
                   tumor.Name,
                   Organs = string.Join(", ", tumor.Organs)
               });
```